# GCC 5 ABI change

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, abi

Fedora [announced](http://fedoramagazine.org/gcc-5-in-fedora-whats-an-abi-and-what-happens-when-we-change-it/) that they might plan on shipping GCC 5 with the new ABI turned off by default. As I understand it, Fedora 22 will continue to use the old ABI and Fedora 23 will use the new ABI. Programs would have to be recompiled in mass quantity.

My question is what does the C++11 standard change from C++03 that breaks ABI compatibility?

Comment: One exemplary thing would be `std::string` being not reference-counted and having small-string optimization.

Comment: Also `std::list`, which now requires a O(1) `size()`.

Comment: There will be no need to recompile programs. Read the announcement thoroughly.

Comment: [GCC5 and the C++11 ABI](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2015/02/05/gcc5-and-the-c11-abi/) @ redhat

Answer (score 0):

There is a page at the GCC wiki about the Cxx11 backward ABI compatibility: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Cxx11AbiCompatibility

> The C++98 language is ABI-compatible with the C++11 language, but several places in the library break compatibility. This makes it dangerous to link C++98 objects with C++11 objects.

Comment: Can you make this more explicit rather than just linking?